Error while trying to alter CDC table on SQL Server
I have to add 2 columns to the CDC tables for tracking, I have done it before, but now suddenly the system is preventing me , as if there was some kind of restriction.

Error code [3764]; Cannot alter the Error: 8277, Severity: -1, State: 0. (Params:). The error is printed in terse mode because there was error during formatting. Tracing, ETW, notifications etc are skipped.
'dbo_entity_CT' because it is being used for Change Data Capture.

I know this is not recommended but I didn't know at the moment of implementation, currently working on removing, but for now I need it to work.
I have tried disabling CDC completely and re enabling it, but no success. Disabling only the table and re enabling.
Adding the columns manually, as they are usually added by code.

Modifying the change tables directly has never been a supported operation.
Following recent GDR security updates, SQL Server 2016 no longer allows these operations at all; they fail with an error (albeit an imperfectly presented one).
The supported option is consuming all pending CDC data, then disabling and reenabling CDC on either side of the base table modifications.

As an unsupported workaround, you can enable global trace flag 15006 to allow modifications as before the GDR security patch:
DBCC TRACEON (15006, -1);

Note The trace flag is not documented for this purpose. If you want to retain supported system status, you'd need to contact Microsoft and ask their permission to use this flag in your circumstances. Otherwise, it's entirely at your own risk.

You could also uninstall the GDR update of course, with the obvious risks.
